# Implement Spring code without annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I want to rewrite this Spring AMQP code without annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51009346Application {

    public static final String QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION = "q1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51009346Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            ReplyObject reply = (ReplyObject) template.convertSendAndReceive("ex", "rk", new RequestObject());
            System.out.println(reply);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf, Listener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "process"));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange te() {
        return new TopicExchange("ex");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(te()).with("rk");
    }

}

class RequestObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

class ReplyObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

@Component
class Listener {

    public ReplyObject process(RequestObject ro) {
        return new ReplyObject();
    }

}
```

I tried this simple Java code without annotations:

Producer code:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.plugin.database.bean.TransactionsBean;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.Connection;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@WebListener
public class ContextServer implements ServletContextListener {

    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);

    admin.declareExchange(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING));
    admin.declareQueue(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, false));

    admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, false)).to(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING)).with(ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION));              
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);

    TransactionsBean obj = new TransactionsBean();      
    obj.setMerchant_id(232323);

    template.setReplyTimeout(600000);
    TransactionsBean reply = (TransactionsBean) template.convertSendAndReceive(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING, ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, obj);
    System.out.println("!!!!! Received Transaction_id " + reply.getTransaction_id());   

    @Override
    public final void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {     
    }
}
```

Consumer code:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.plugin.database.bean.TransactionsBean;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @SpringBootApplication
@WebListener
public class ContextServer implements ServletContextListener {

    private static String QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION = "processing-process-queue";
    private static final String EXCHANGE_PROCESSING = "processing";
    private static final String ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION = "processing.trx.process";

    @Override
    public final void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {

        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    admin.declareExchange(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING));
    admin.declareQueue(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, false));

    admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, false))
            .to(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING)).with(ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION));
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf, Listener listener) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "process"));
    container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());//basic converter for java.io.Serializable POJO
    return container;
    }

    @Override
    public final void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    @Component
    class Listener {

        public TransactionsBean process(TransactionsBean ro) {
            TransactionsBean obj = new TransactionsBean();
            obj.setTransaction_id("some_id");
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Error stack:

```
   13:20:44,797 INFO  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) Container initialized for queues: [amq.rabbitmq.reply-to]
13:20:44,803 INFO  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, consumerTag=amq.ctag-oWxWZJEPgZyP-gRxWe-Ifg identity=42eb5972] started
13:20:49,846 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./rest_api: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./rest_api: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:251)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deployment.rest_api.war//org.rest.api.context.ContextServer.contextInitialized(ContextServer.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:215)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:249)
    ... 10 more

13:20:49,885 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "rest_api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./rest_api" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
13:20:49,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "rest_api.war" (runtime-name : "rest_api.war")
```

Message from Producer is successfully send.
 I get NPE at this line in Producer: `reply.getTransaction_id()`
What is the proper way to implement the Consumer without annotations with basic Java code?

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009346/receive-and-send-java-objects-with-spring-amqp/51010675#51010675), if you are not familiar with Spring, the best way to get started is to use Spring Boot. Go to http://start.spring.io and build a new project after selecting RabbitMQ as a dependency. That is exactly what I did for the example code there.

If you **insist** on rolling your own code and not using Spring to manage the dependencies and lifecycles of these components; you need to do that work yourself - calling `afterPropertiesSet()`, `start()` etc.

> I get NPE

That is entirely insufficient information. You need to show the complete stack trace, and all of your code, including the `TransactionsBean`.

Trust me; "without annotations" means you have to write a lot more code yourself.

**EDIT**

> `System.out.println(" !!!!!!!! Transaction_id " + receivedobj.getTransaction_id());`

Of course you'll get an NPE - you don't actually check the returned object is not null; the template has a default reply timeout of 5 seconds, after which `null` is returned.

The container won't do anything until it is `start()`ed; again; please learn to use Spring to manage the lifecycle of these objects.

Comment: I added everything that I tried so far. But I need some help in order to make the code working. I will definitely start to learn Spring but for now to make this proof of concept code to work as fast as possible I need your help.

Comment: I tried to apply the changes but I get NPE. Can you advice how to fix the issue?

Comment: You get an NPE because you don't check for a null result. It looks to me like you are sending the message before Spring has initialized the application context. According to the `contextInitialized` javadocs: `>Receives notification that the web application initialization process is starting.` Wait until the application is up before using RabbitMQ.

Comment: is there any workaround? For example call Spring right after contextInitialized?

Comment: You need to wait until later - for example like in the `ApplicationRunner` in my example - those beans are run after spring has completed initialization.

Answer (score 1):

There multiple problems here:

1. As mentioned above by @Gary Russell there is no connection timeout at first
2. The root problem of receiving `null` is that `convertSendAndReceive` operate with POJO which should be serializable and Serializer should be described on Consumer side:

```java
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf, Listener listener) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "process"));
    container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());//basic converter for java.io.Serializable POJO
    return container;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but after I applied the changes I get NPE.