# How to properly close Spring AMQP connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

What is the proper way to properly close Spring AMQP connection

```
protected CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
protected AmqpAdmin admin;
protected RabbitTemplate processingTemplate;


private static Class<ContextServer> applicationClass = ContextServer.class;

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
// do something
}

public void close() {
    connectionFactory.destroy();
    admin = null;
    processingTemplate = null;
}
```

The only solution that I can think of is to use destroy. Is there some better way?

Comment: Why would you need to close it? That is going to happen automatically when you stop the application, unless of course you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: For example stop Wildly or underlay the package

Comment: That stops the application and closes connections. You are trying to outsmart the framework that already does all of this.

Comment: Ok, should I use connectionFactory.destroy();?

Comment: No.. You shouldn't do anything, it is all handled for you by Spring.

Comment: If you are (again - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009346/receive-and-send-java-objects-with-spring-amqp)) creating these objects without Spring's knowledge then, yes, you will have to destroy the factory (we added a synonym method with a more friendly name `resetConnection()`). But you really should just let Spring manage everything. It will make your life easier - I have explained this several times to you recently. You will have to stop the container(s) first - otherwise they will simply re-open the connection.